# A problem based on number theory

Tags: number-theory

Let x=a (mod m) and x=b (mod n) be two congruences then what is a condition that the system of congruences has
1. Finitely many solutions
2.Infinity many solutions
3. No solution
4.Unique solution.
 My attempt:I restrict x then it has unique solution by Chinese remainder theorem. I have no idea about the others. Please help me.

Comment: You'll want the Chinese remainder theorem.

Comment: @jgon Judging from the question, I bet the OP hasn't learned the Chinese Remainder Theorem, and that  that is really the whole point of the problem.

Comment: @Dzoooks I sorta figure that, but I put effort into questions proportional to the effort I perceive has been put into the question. So when the question looks like this, that's about as helpful as I get. (Unless I find the question interesting ofc.)

Comment: Try a few examples: let $a=b=2$ and $m=4$ and $n=6$.  Let $a=b=2$ and $m=4$, $n=5$.  Let $a=2$ and $b=3$ and $m=4$ and $n=6$.

Comment: For a=b=2 and m=4,n=6; x=2+4p, x=2+6q (p,q are integers) gives 4p=6q => p=(3/2)q which is possible if q is even integer.

Comment: For a=b=2,m=4,n=5 ; x=2+4p=2+5q gives p=(5/4)q which is possible if q is multiple of 4 . By Chinese remainder theorem it has unique solution

Comment: For a=2,b=3;m=4,n=6; x=2+4p=3+6q gives p=(1+6q)/4 which is not possible. So it has no integer solution.

Comment: When we take m is multiple of n or n is multiple of m then sometimes solution exists and sometimes it is not exist. So I'm not reaching the conclusion. Please explain and clear my doubt.